# Как достать значение из ответа Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
var ownId = 0;
var ownPhoto = '';

sendRequest({
  url: getUrl('users.get', {fields: 'photo_100'}),
  success: function(data) {
    data = data.response;
    ownId = data[0].id;
    ownPhoto = data[0].photo_100;
  }
})
```

Данная функция отправляет Ajax запрос к VK API(Что в принципе не важно для этого вопроса). Эта функция создана с помощью jQuery, в `data` я получаю данные, которые мне нужны, а теперь мне нужно каким-то образом отправить эти данные в переменные, что определены выше. Когда я это пытаюсь сделать так, как показано в коде, то значение не меняются. Как можно решить этот вопрос?

`success` это колбек, который вызывается при успешном получении ответа, тоже самое что в `$.ajax` в jQuery.

Comment: вынесите определение функции success на один уровень с переменными ownId и ownPhoto

Comment: Как вы поняли, что переменные не меняются?

Comment: console.log(ownId) после завершения запроса, за пределами функции sendRequest. Равно 0. В внутри самой функции success не 0

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi отвечая, упоминайте мой ник, чтобы уведомление прилетело ;) [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937138/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-success-%D0%B2-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5#comment1556748_937138) подробно описал, почему так происходит (второй комментарий).

Comment: @MishaSaidow, а что, если у меня нет возможности работать с этой переменной в коллбэке?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)